# What does " Any award recognition is just gravy " mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, ambiguity, sentence-meaning

The interviewer asked the actor "What would an Oscar nomination mean for you?", and he answered, "Any award recognition is just gravy".

Can anybody please clarify the actor's answer?

What do "award recognition" and "gravy" mean here?

Comment: The nomination is a form of recognition even without winning the award. The actor is acting humble. Gravy is anything extra.

Comment: ***gravy*** here is a less common (but [rapidly gaining traction](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%27s+all+gravy&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=3)) alternative to *Any award recognition [is just **the icing on the cake***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22medal+was+just+the+icing+on+the+cake%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, "award recognition" refers to the act of being recognised by the Academy in the form of a nomination. So, really, 'recognition' is interchangeable with 'nomination' in this sense because it is the means by which he is recognized.

As for 'gravy', this is an unusual usage but I suspect it relates to the American idiom 'it's all gravy', meaning loosely 'it's all good!'.